# Data from Angular .then function is not displayed on page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code in my `stucontrollers.j`

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var stucontrollers = angular.module("stucontrollers", []);
stucontrollers.controller("GetStudentsList",
    function GetStudentsList($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/students'
    }).then(function(data) {
        $scope.students = data;
    });
});
```

and in my `view`, I have this

```
<div ng-app="StudentApp">
    <div ng-controller="GetStudentsList">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>FistName</th>
                    <th>LastName</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Gender  </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in students">
                    <td>{{item.Id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.FirstName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.LastName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Age}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Gender}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in my `app.js` this is what I have

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var module = angular.module("StudentApp", ["stucontrollers"]);
```

This is in my `StudentsController.cs`

```
// GET: api/Students
        public IQueryable<Student> GetStudents()
        {
            return db.Students;
        }
```

I am trying to get the list of the students into my view but I am only able to get it in the response of the page inspector not on the page itself. What am I doing wrong. Thank you.

**EDIT**
Now I am able to see my data in the console. But I still couldn't see it in my page. Below is the data I get in the console.

```
data
:
Array(2)
0
:
{Id: 1, FirstName: "Juan", LastName: "Dela Cruz", Age: 25, Gender: "Male"}
1
:
{Id: 2, FirstName: "Maria ", LastName: "Makiling", Age: 30, Gender: "Female"}
```

Comment: Hello :D Could you post your return from the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `$scope.$apply()` after setting the value.

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/students'
    }).then(function(data) {
      $scope.students = data;
      $scope.$apply();
    });
```

or simply

```
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/api/students'
    }).then(function(data) {
      $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.students = data;
      });
    });
```

From the [$apply documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of the AngularJS framework.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is not necessary. the "then" is inside a normal digest cycle, should not be necessary to use $apply. Also, using $apply where is not needed gives performance issues and then we have these React ppl saying AngularJs has poor performance... @Ibanez1700, inspect the value of data inside "then" function, it may have a different structure to the one you're expecting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    /// <reference path="../angular.js" />
    var stucontrollers = angular.module("stucontrollers", []);
    stucontrollers.controller("GetStudentsList",
    function GetStudentsList($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/students'
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.students = response.data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To debug this, try setting value of $scope.students directly, like this:

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var stucontrollers = angular.module("stucontrollers", []);
stucontrollers.controller("GetStudentsList",
    function GetStudentsList($scope, $http) {
    $scope.students = [{Id: 1, FirstName: "John"}];
});
```

Then either one of two things happens:

a) You see John in the list: this means ng-controller and ng-repeat work. Problem in in fetching the data. Try next by console.logging your response.

b) You don't see John in the list: There is something wrong even before the request happens.

Comment: I see John in the list. It's in fetching the data that's at fault here.

Comment: What happens if you console.log data in the then() callback?

Comment: I'll check. Just a sec.

Comment: Now I see.. It cannot find the /api/GetStudents. How can this be when the name of the controller is StudentsController and the name of the method is GetStudents(). I tried using the /Students/GetStudents already

Comment: I changed the url to include ../ at the beginning. I can see the results in the console. But still I do not see it in the page.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, You might as well try it :

```
/// <reference path="../angular.js" />
var stucontrollers = angular.module("stucontrollers", []);
stucontrollers.controller("GetStudentsList",
    function GetStudentsList($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/api/students'
    }).then(function(data) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.students = data;
    });
  });
});
```